# CSS WOFF Font - Deploy without @Face-Font

Tags: css, font-face

I was reading this article and noticed it said if you are only supplying WOFF font to a browser you don't need to use the @Font-Face syntax:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

```
Or even just WOFF.

You then use it like this:
 body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

I wanted to ask if this is possible as I'm not sure how this would path to the font file eg: 'myfont.woff'?

Is it possible to include a WOFF webfont without @Font-Face?

thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is not saying not to use @font-face, he's saying you **declare** it like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

and then **use** it like this:

```
body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

When he says you can use *just* WOFF, he means that you can probably get away with this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: I understand now and will tick once the time limit is - thanks heaps... once question - would you include ttf as well? don't think I need to support those older browsers... thoughts?

Comment: To be honest, I'm still using the BulletProof Font Face Syntax - http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax - but I'm also still supporting IE8 a lot of the time as well. I'm not sure what format(s) Android supports, and there's still quite a few 2.3 installations going around out there. Depends on what you support. If you're okay working with only modern browsers, then just go with WOFF, but using fontsquirrel to generate a complete package isn't much more difficult IMO.